# DJango 1.9 Profile register + update

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-templates, profile

basically I want to extend User, with some additional data.
Everything good in the model, is as supposed following the documentation.

models.py

```
class perfil(models.Model):
Sexos = (
         ('M','Masculino'),
         ('F','Femenino'),
         )

user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
ci = models.CharField(max_length = 10, blank=True, null=True)
sexo = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = Sexos, blank=True, null=True)
fechaNac = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
foto = models.CharField(max_length = 300,blank=True, null=True)
tlf = models.CharField(max_length = 11,blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user
```

On the other hand I also need to register a new user, entering the profile at the same time, so I made this:

views.py

```
def registroUsuario(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/registro')
if request.method == "POST":
    form = formRegistroUsuario(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():   
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        nombre = form.cleaned_data['nombre']
        apellidos = form.cleaned_data['apellidos']
        f_nac = form.cleaned_data['f_nac']
        correo = form.cleaned_data['correo']
        tlf = form.cleaned_data['tlf']
        clave = form.cleaned_data['clave']
        sexo = form.cleaned_data['sexo']
        ci = form.cleaned_data['ci']
        entry = User.objects.create_user(username= username ,email = correo, password = clave)
        entry.first_name = nombre
        entry.last_name = apellidos
        entry.save()
        p_entry = perfil.objects.get(user = entry)
        p_entry.ci = ci
        p_entry.sexo = sexo
        p_entry.fechaNac = f_nac
        p_entry.tlf = tlf
        p_entry.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/registro')
    else:
        return render(request,'registro/home.html', {'form': form})
    pass
else:
    form = formRegistroUsuario()
    return render(request,'registro/home.html', {'form': form})
```

But I think I'm not doing it the rigth way, from what I've seen, but I can´t seem to understand how to make it work in another way.

Also I need to be able to update my profile, so I made those 2

```
class userForm(forms.ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField(disabled = True, label = 'Nombre de usuario')
first_name = forms.CharField(disabled = True, label = 'Nombre')
last_name = forms.CharField(disabled = True, label = 'Apellido')
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label = 'Contrasena', required = False)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password']

class perfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
fechaNac = forms.DateField(disabled = True, label = 'Fecha de nacimiento')
tlf = forms.CharField(label = 'Numero de telefono')
ci = forms.CharField(disabled = True, label = 'CI')
correo = forms.CharField(disabled = True)
class Meta:
    model = perfil
    exclude = ('user',)
```

And views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/registro/login/')
def editarUsuario(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    userform = userForm(instance = request.user, data = request.POST)
    profileform =  perfilForm(instance = request.user.perfil, data = request.POST)
    if userform.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid():
        user = userform.save(commit = False)
        user.user = request.user
        if userform.cleaned_data['password']:
            user.set_password(userform.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save()
        profile = profileform.save(commit = False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/registro/editar')
    else:
        return render(request,'registro/editar.html', {'formUser': userform,
                                                      'formPerfil': profileform})
else :
    formUser = userForm(instance = request.user)
    formPerfil = perfilForm(instance = request.user.perfil)
    return render(request,'registro/editar.html', {'formUser': formUser,
                                                  'formPerfil': formPerfil})
```

Would like to know how could I improve my code to make it the Django way.
Also, bit offtopic, I would like to show those disabled = True fields on userForm  as labels, instead of fields with readonly, how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create a `User` and a `UserProfile` instance at the same time like you're doing in your code above, but unless you are going to use atomic transactions, it could cause problems if the user is created properly, but the profile has an error. You can get around this by putting all of the user profile fields in one custom class (as I will explain below), or you can let users fill in their profile on a separate page after registration.

**To make your own `User` class:**

You can extend replace the default `User` class with your own class (let's call it `MyUser`, preferably subclassing either `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`. You can then refer to new class in your settings as `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'models.MyUser'`, and in your foreign keys as `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` (remember to use `from django.conf import settings`).

Here's more information on the subject from the Django Docs, which explain it really well:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model